# The operation can’t be completed because an unexpected error occurred (error code -8058)

Tags: xcode, macos, copy

Today morning, I tried to copy my Xcode project and pasted it in Backup Folder. I got this above issue.

> The operation can’t be completed because an unexpected error occurred
>   (error code -8058)

I believe that this project may have a folder with same name in a sub-folders. This is happening only in this folder. Other project's directory Copy/Paste is working fine. Any Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an expert but some quick Googling leads me that solving -8058 is done by renaming the file altogether (and then possibly restarting your machine).

Comment: Don't use adhoc backups; use source control and host the repo on github (public) or bitbucket (private).

Comment: this is general copy/paste issue, don't relate it with github or bitbucket.

Answer (score 4):

You can try following steps.

1. Try to copy - paste or duplicate another folder. If you can copy paste it , than the problem is with that specific folder only.
2. Now try to copy contents of that folder one by one.
3. Some folders might me copied easily. One by one copying the folder , you will find the culprit.
   Check the contents and remove it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

At least in my case, the error occurred because one of the "files" in the source was a Unix domain socket (on a Linux box running CentOS 6.5).  (FYI, this is an IPC mechanism that uses a special type of file in the filesystem as a rendezvous point between two processes).

Given that, I'm guessing that it's possible to get that error with other "special" file types also -- e.g., hard link.

HTH...